# can not setInterval in onLocationChanged

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-location

I am trying the 'LocationUpdates' sample from http://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html . This application gets and prints location notifications.

I am trying to change the interval of the location updates according to my latest location.

So - I had added mLocationRequest.setInterval() into onLocationChanged

The result is very wrong. My application is bombarded with many location updates (few a second!!!!)

My only change to the sample is this:

```
private int x=0;
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // Report to the UI that the location was updated
    mConnectionStatus.setText(R.string.location_updated);

    // In the UI, set the latitude and longitude to the value received
    mLatLng.setText(String.valueOf(x++));

    mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);          // Change 1
    mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, this); // Change 2
}
```

How can I change the interval inside onLocationChanged ?

I think that the problem is that requestLocationUpdates resets the last request, and then immediately sends another notification. so a loop is created. (faster than the fastest interval). so I need a reliable way to change the interval of a 'live' LocationRequest

Comment: This also does not work:  locClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, this,Looper.getMainLooper());

Comment: Have you tried the `mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);` line outside the `onLocationChanged()` callback? For example, at initialization time of the `mLocationRequest` object.

Comment: yes - its actually doesn't matter where you call it.

Comment: Have you tried other events like "onbefore" in the event name?

Answer (score 1):

You are not supposed to call `mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, this);` inside `onLocationChanged(Location location)`

since you are registering the listener again, and you will get the first call immediately.

so what i would do would be:

1. dont call `mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, this);` and see if anyways `mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);` is taking effect
2. if this doesnt work, try to unregister the listener, and then use a trick to wait before registering it again with the new settings, something like:

   ```
    Handler h = new Handler();
    @Override
      public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
       //... all your code


        mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);          
        mLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(LocationListener listener)

        h.postDelayed (new Runnable(){

          public void run(){
            mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, YOUROUTTERCLASS.this); 
          }

        }, 1000);

       }
   ```

   So during one second there is not registered listener, so you wont get any updated, and after that, the listener is registerered with that interval.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(long millis)`
As mentioned in developer.android.com :

> This allows your application to passively acquire locations at a rate faster than it actively acquires locations, saving power. Unlike setInterval(long), this parameter is exact. Your application will never receive updates faster than this value.

Comment: I did it, and set the fastest rate to 1000. Nevertheless I still get many notifications a second !?

Comment: Then maybe removing previous updates and then starting a new LocationRequest might help, although android says "mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, this);" replace old ones but there are many bugs yet to be resolved ;)

Comment: I think that the problem is that requestLocationUpdates resets the last request, and then immediately sends another notification. so a loop is created. (faster than the fastest interval). so I need a reliable way to change the interval

Answer (score 0):

Try to use :

```
mLocationRequest.requestLocationUpdates("gps", 1000, 0, this);
```

However I don't agree to do a requestLocationUpdates in onLocationChanged event; In my opinion should be setted outside onLocationChanged Event...

Comment: It does not matter where I call it from. The point is that when you reset the updates, you might receive the next notification very fast, even faster that the fastest rate.

Comment: It is probably not possible to change the interval at all. only restart the request, which is unreliable.

Comment: My solution is to compare the current notification time to the previous notification time, and ignore it if they are too close - absurd.